# Intriguing assembly for comparing std::optional of primitive types

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, x86-64, c++17

Valgrind picked up a flurry *Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)* in one of my unit tests.

Inspecting the assembly, I realized that the following code:

```
bool operator==(MyType const& left, MyType const& right) {
    // ... some code ...
    if (left.getA() != right.getA()) { return false; }
    // ... some code ...
    return true;
}
```

Where `MyType::getA() const -> std::optional<std::uint8_t>`, generated the following assembly:

```
   0x00000000004d9588 <+108>:   xor    eax,eax
   0x00000000004d958a <+110>:   cmp    BYTE PTR [r14+0x1d],0x0
   0x00000000004d958f <+115>:   je     0x4d9597 <... function... +123>
x  0x00000000004d9591 <+117>:   mov    r15b,BYTE PTR [r14+0x1c]
x  0x00000000004d9595 <+121>:   mov    al,0x1

   0x00000000004d9597 <+123>:   xor    edx,edx
   0x00000000004d9599 <+125>:   cmp    BYTE PTR [r13+0x1d],0x0
   0x00000000004d959e <+130>:   je     0x4d95ae <... function... +146>
x  0x00000000004d95a0 <+132>:   mov    dil,BYTE PTR [r13+0x1c]
x  0x00000000004d95a4 <+136>:   mov    dl,0x1
x  0x00000000004d95a6 <+138>:   mov    BYTE PTR [rsp+0x97],dil

   0x00000000004d95ae <+146>:   cmp    al,dl
   0x00000000004d95b0 <+148>:   jne    0x4da547 <... function... +4139>

   0x00000000004d95b6 <+154>:   cmp    r15b,BYTE PTR [rsp+0x97]
   0x00000000004d95be <+162>:   je     0x4d95c8 <... function... +172>

    => Jump on uninitialized

   0x00000000004d95c0 <+164>:   test   al,al
   0x00000000004d95c2 <+166>:   jne    0x4da547 <... function... +4139>
```

Where I marked with `x` the statements that are not executed (jumped over) in the case where the optional is NOT set.

The member `A` here is at offset `0x1c` into `MyType`. Checking the layout of `std::optional` we see that:

- `+0x1d` corresponds to `bool _M_engaged`,
- `+0x1c` corresponds to `std::uint8_t _M_payload` (inside an anonymous union).

The code of interest for `std::optional` is:

```
constexpr explicit operator bool() const noexcept
{ return this->_M_is_engaged(); }

// Comparisons between optional values.
template<typename _Tp, typename _Up>
constexpr auto operator==(const optional<_Tp>& __lhs, const optional<_Up>& __rhs) -> __optional_relop_t<decltype(declval<_Tp>() == declval<_Up>())>
{
    return static_cast<bool>(__lhs) == static_cast<bool>(__rhs)
         && (!__lhs || *__lhs == *__rhs);
}
```

Here, we can see that gcc transformed the code quite substantially; if I understand it correctly, in C this gives:

```
char rsp[0x148]; // simulate the stack

/* comparisons of prior data members */

/*
0x00000000004d9588 <+108>:   xor    eax,eax
0x00000000004d958a <+110>:   cmp    BYTE PTR [r14+0x1d],0x0
0x00000000004d958f <+115>:   je     0x4d9597 <... function... +123>
0x00000000004d9591 <+117>:   mov    r15b,BYTE PTR [r14+0x1c]
0x00000000004d9595 <+121>:   mov    al,0x1
*/

int eax = 0;
if (__lhs._M_engaged == 0) { goto b123; }
bool r15b = __lhs._M_payload;
eax = 1;

b123:
/*
0x00000000004d9597 <+123>:   xor    edx,edx
0x00000000004d9599 <+125>:   cmp    BYTE PTR [r13+0x1d],0x0
0x00000000004d959e <+130>:   je     0x4d95ae <... function... +146>
0x00000000004d95a0 <+132>:   mov    dil,BYTE PTR [r13+0x1c]
0x00000000004d95a4 <+136>:   mov    dl,0x1
0x00000000004d95a6 <+138>:   mov    BYTE PTR [rsp+0x97],dil
*/

int edx = 0;
if (__rhs._M_engaged == 0) { goto b146; }
rdi = __rhs._M_payload;
edx = 1;
rsp[0x97] = rdi;

b146:
/*
0x00000000004d95ae <+146>:   cmp    al,dl
0x00000000004d95b0 <+148>:   jne    0x4da547 <... function... +4139>
*/

if (eax != edx) { goto end; } // return false

/*
0x00000000004d95b6 <+154>:   cmp    r15b,BYTE PTR [rsp+0x97]
0x00000000004d95be <+162>:   je     0x4d95c8 <... function... +172>
*/

//  Flagged by valgrind
if (r15b == rsp[097]) { goto b172; } // next data member

/*
0x00000000004d95c0 <+164>:   test   al,al
0x00000000004d95c2 <+166>:   jne    0x4da547 <... function... +4139>
*/

if (eax == 1) { goto end; } // return false

b172:

/* comparison of following data members */

end:
    return false;
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
//  Note how the operands of || are inversed.
return static_cast<bool>(__lhs) == static_cast<bool>(__rhs)
         && (*__lhs == *__rhs || !__lhs);
```

I **think** that the assembly is correct, if strange. That is, as far as I can see, the result of the comparison between uninitialized values does not actually influence the result of the function (and unlike C or C++, I do expect comparing junk in x86 assembly NOT to be UB):

1. If one optional is `nullopt` and the other is set, then the conditional jump at `+148` jumps to `end` (`return false`), OK.
2. If both optionals are set, then the comparison reads initialized values, OK.

So the only case of interest is when both optionals are `nullopt`:

- if the values compare equal, then the code concludes that the optionals are equal, which is true since they are both `nullopt`,
- otherwise, the code concludes that the optionals are equal if `__lhs._M_engaged` is false, which is true.

In either case, the code therefore concludes that both optionals are equal when both are `nullopt`; CQFD.

---

This is the first instance I see of gcc generating apparently "benign" uninitialized reads, and therefore I have a few questions:

1. **Are uninitialized reads OK in assembly (x84_64)?**
2. **Is this the syndrome of a failed optimization (reversing `||`) which could trigger in non-benign circumstances?**

For now, I am leaning toward annotating the few functions with `optimize(1)` as a work-around to prevent optimizations from kicking in. Fortunately, the identified functions are not performance critical.

---

Environment:

- compiler: gcc 7.3
- compile flags: `-std=c++17 -g -Wall -Werror -O3 -flto` (+ appropriate includes)
- link flags: `-O3 -flto` (+ appropriate libraries)

Note: can appear with `-O2` instead of `-O3`, but never without `-flto`.

---

*Fun facts*

*In the full code, this pattern appears 32 times in the function outlined above, for various payloads : `std::uint8_t`, `std::uint32_t`, `std::uint64_t` and even a `struct { std::int64_t; std::int8_t; }`.*

*It only appears in a few big `operator==` comparing types with ~40 data members, not in smaller ones. And it does not appear for the `std::optional<std::string_view>` even in those specific functions (which call into `std::char_traits` for the comparison).*

*Finally, infuriatingly, isolating the function in question in its own binary makes the "problem" disappear. The mythical MCVE is proving elusive.*

Comment: It's also strange that `+138` stores `dil` on the stack and `+154` uses that instead of the unchanged register.

Comment: *"Finally, infuriatingly, isolating the function in question in its own binary makes the "problem" disappear. The mythical MCVE is proving elusive."* I would rather say that there is probably a problem / UB with code related to those *"~40 data members"* or somewhere else. `-Wno-return-type` is suspicious as well.

Comment: Afaik there is no such thing as ub in asm. If some memory is uninitialized then you are free to find anything there (but 0 is mostly probable as OS fills given memory pages with 0s)

Comment: @bartop well, there is *some* UB, e.g. with threads

Comment: @o11c Interesting, could you give some article?

Comment: @VTT: `-Wno-return-type` is used because gcc complains (in another function) that a function has no `return` after `throw std::runtime_error();`... and I'm not going to add a bogus `return` to avoid a flawed warning.

Comment: @VTT: As for UB, yes, this was my first thought. Until I realized that the assembly would *always* return the right answer, even after performing uninitialized reads, at which point I started suspecting a clever optimization. There might still be UB, of course, however the function in question is literally a sequence of `if (left.getA() != right.getA()) { return false; }` and those `getA` are dumb: they return members of primitive or `std::optional<<primitive>>` types, mostly. I checked `std::optional` but did not see anything untoward.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Are you sure that it is the actual cause and control does not flow out of that function at different route? [gcc does not seem to emit that warning for plain cases of throw instead return.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZvGZycA56btiNawA)

Comment: @bartop see e.g. http://preshing.com/20120930/weak-vs-strong-memory-models/ and other links from that. The StoreLoad case is classic UB.

Comment: @Jester: Yes, I was surprised at the spill too. It doesn't seem very efficient.

Comment: @VTT I removed the `-Wreturn-type` from the makefile, it was unnecessary for this executable. The problem still occurs.

Comment: @bartop [There is absolutely undefined behavior in assembly](https://twitter.com/volatile_void/status/928752732525203456)

Comment: @Jester: The store can be jumped over by the `je` to `+146`, so it's possible to reach `+154` without necessarily having `dil == [rsp+0x97]`.

Comment: @o11c: asm data races and so on are very different from C++ UB.   In C++, a program that will *eventually* encounter UB can do absolutely anything even before the program actually hits UB (if it's provable at compile time that it will).  And the whole rest of the program behaviour afterward is also completely unspecified.  In x86 asm, the worst that happens is that a single register has an unknown value (or you don't know which of two possible values, old or new, it has).  But [if your code doesn't depend on that register value, you're fine, unlike in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40565835)

Comment: Some ISAs have undefined behaviour, like early ARM if you use the same register for multiple operands of a multiply, the behaviour is unpredictable.  Or MIPS, if you put a branch in the branch-delay slot, the behaviour is unpredictable.  But presumably there are still limits and you can't crash the machine or break other processes (in a multi-user system like Unix, it would be bad if an unprivileged user-space process could break anything for other users).

Comment: @PeterCordes: I agree that `dil != [rsp+097]` in general, however `[rsp+097]` only appears in this very section of code, so it's unclear why the compiler loads a value in `dil` and spills into `[rsp+097]` into the same basic-block, and then reads from `[rsp+097]` instead of reading from `dil`. It's also very inefficient of the compiler to not *reuse* the same stack slot over and over for all 32 instances of such spills that occur in this function, and instead reserve a separate slot for each, and never use two of the slots at the same time.

Comment: That does sound silly.  IDK why gcc does so badly here.  Is clang any better?  Especially if both are using the same libstdc++ implementation of `std::optional`.  (i.e. don't use `-stdlib=libc++` with clang if that was the default or what you usually do.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: I haven't tried Clang. To be honest, even with gcc it takes a very specific configuration of optimization flags and sources to reach this, most of the time I have a completely different implementation. In general, I get [something like that instead](https://godbolt.org/g/tNNpaX), where the first section compares the flag for equality, and then the first bit of L7 check whether the flag is set before actually checking the content. It's only with `-flto` on some specific (big) sources that I get this weird assembly.

Comment: Right, probably something gets too big for some threshold in a gcc optimization pass, and it then doesn't run that optimization and you get crap.  I don't know gcc internals well enough to guess beyond that.  And BTW, I find the `\s+` option on Godbolt makes asm harder to read, all jumbled together.  But it was the default for a while and people keep posting links or worse copying output into SO questions with it enabled :/

Comment: @PeterCordes: Wow, thanks for the tip about `\s+`; I hadn't tweaked anything and it really is better without!

Comment: Glad someone else agrees that it's ugly.  I did already convince Matt to change the default back to not that with a horrible ICC-comments example: https://github.com/mattgodbolt/compiler-explorer/issues/963, so in future people will have to turn this on manually for narrow output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In x86 asm, the worst that happens is that a single register has an unknown value (or you don't know which of two possible values it has, old or new, in case of possible memory-ordering). But [if your code doesn't depend on that register value, you're fine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40565835), unlike in C++.  C++ UB means your whole program is in theory completely hosed after one signed-integer overflow, and even before that along code-paths that the compiler can see will lead to UB.  Nothing like that ever happens in asm, at least not in unprivileged user-space code.

(There might be a few things you can do to basically cause system-wide unpredictable behaviour in the kernel, by setting control registers in weird ways or putting inconsistent things into page tables or descriptors, but that's not going to happen from something like this, even if you were compiling kernel code.)

---

Some ISAs have "unpredictable behaviour", like early ARM if you use the same register for multiple operands of a multiply, the behaviour is unpredictable.  IDK if this allows breaking the pipeline and corrupting other registers, or if it's restricted to just an unexpected multiply result.  The latter would be my guess.

Or MIPS, if you put a branch in the branch-delay slot, the behaviour is unpredictable.  (Handling exceptions is messy because of branch-delay slots...).  But presumably there are still limits and you can't crash the machine or break other processes (in a multi-user system like Unix, it would be bad if an unprivileged user-space process could break anything for other users).

Very early MIPS also had load-delay slots, and multiply delay slots: you couldn't use the result of a load in the next instruction.  Presumably you might get the old value of the register if you read it too early, or maybe just garbage.  MIPS = Minimally Interlocked Pipeline Stages; they wanted to offload the stalling to software, but it turned out that adding a NOP when the compiler couldn't find anything useful to do next bloated binaries and led to slower overall code vs. having the hardware stall when necessary.  But we're stuck with branch-delay slots because removing them would change the ISA, unlike relaxing a restriction on something early software didn't do.

Answer (score 6):

There are no trap values in x86 integer formats, so reading and comparing uninitialized values generates unpredictable truth/false values and no other direct harm.

In a cryptographic context, the state of the uninitialized values causing a different branch to be taken could leak into timing information leaking or other side-channel attacks.  But cryptographic hardening is probably not what you are worried about.

The fact that gcc does uninitialized reads when it doesn't matter if the read gives the wrong value doesn't mean it will do it when it matters.

Comment: The fact that `std::optional<std::string_view>` is codegened in the expected way (first checking whether the option is set, then dereferencing) is certainly a point in the direction that gcc is careful about this optimization.

Comment: Valgrind is not complaining about reading uninitialized data, but about a conditional branch being executed while the condition codes are set according to an operation on uninitialized data. So the only way this could be a false positive is if both branches were semantically equivalent, but in this case there would be no reason to emit the branch instruction.

Comment: @SimonRichter No, they can be semantically distinct, *if* the data is only partly uninitialized.  Which appears to be the case here: if the data is equal, it is known that they are equal (either nullopt&nullopt, or set&set).  If the data are not equal, either they are nullopt & nullopt & garbage, or they are set&set.  So a second check is made on (one of the) the is_nullopt fields.  We know more when they compare equal than we do if they don't compare equal.

Answer (score 0):

I would not be so sure that it is caused by compiler error. Possibly there is some UB in Your code which allows compiler to optimize more aggressivelly Your code. Anyway, to the questions:

1. UB is not an issue in assembly. In most general case, what is left under the address You are refering to will be read. Of course most OSes fill memory pages before giving them to program, but your variable most probably resides on stack, so most probably it contains garbage data. Soo, as long You are ok with random data comparison (which is quite bad, as may spuriously give different results) assembly is valid
2. Most probably it is syndrome of reversed comparison